# systemctl status ufw.service failure

Tags: server, ufw

```
systemd[1]: Starting Uncomplicated firewall...
ufw-init[1232]: iptables-restore: line 5 failed
systemd[1]: ufw.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE

systemd[1]: ufw.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
systemd[1]: Failed to start Uncomplicated firewall.
```

any ideas how to fix the error?

where to find iptables-restore line 5?

Using Ubuntu Server 22.04

Thanks

Comment: Is `iptables` installed?  It's necessary for UFW to work proper

Comment: iptables is already the newest version (1.8.7-1ubuntu5).

Comment: second sever, built at the same time gets this status:                                  
     ufw.service - Uncomplicated firewall
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ufw.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (exited) since Tue 2023-02-21 23:21:42 EST; 3 days ago
       Docs: man:ufw(8)
   Main PID: 723 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 127ms          crazy..RB

Comment: Is on the running server package  iptables-persistent installed?

Comment: It looks like the ufw service file invokes `iptables-restore` via its internal `/lib/ufw/ufw-init-functions` to load rules - I wonder if one of your rules files has an error? If so, you might be able to identify it with something like `for f in /etc/ufw/*.rules; do echo "$f:"; sudo /sbin/iptables-restore --test "$f"; done`

Comment: awesome idea!
iptables-restore v1.8.7 (nf_tables): Couldn't load match `rt':No such file or directory

Error occurred at line: 24
Try `iptables-restore -h' or 'iptables-restore --help' for more information.
/etc/ufw/before.rules:
/etc/ufw/user6.rules:
/etc/ufw/user.rules:

Comment: Sucess! thank you. reinstall of iptables-persistent cleared it up.
 ● ufw.service - Uncomplicated firewall
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ufw.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (exited) since Sun 2023-02-26 14:41:07 EST; 10s ago
       Docs: man:ufw(8)
    Process: 268005 ExecStart=/lib/ufw/ufw-init start quiet (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 268005 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 7ms - RB